# How do I resize the window of screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

Just got into using Screen for remote pair-programming purposes with Vim.

Was wondering if there was a way to resize the windows as our terminal space is somewhat very limited with the default settings.

Currently I'm getting into screen like this:

```
User 1: screen -R test
User 2: screen -x -R test
```

Comment: Resize the terminal window or the screen view port? The latter would be C+a F (that's an uppercase F)

Comment: Why don't you repost your comment as a answer @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: There must be additional tags other than 'screen' that fit this question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of the time `screen` will simply resize the windows it owns whenever you resize the terminal emulator that owns the screen session.

However, when someone connects to your screen session and your screen is wider or higher than that person's you or that person can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> (uppercase `F`, i.e. with <kbd>Shift</kbd> held down) to adjust the size of the current window (inside `screen`) to that of the terminal emulator in which `screen` runs.